# Using breqn in unnumbered equation in LyX

Tags: lyx, breqn

I finally found a way to use automatic line breaking in long math formulas in LyX from the last post in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904807/lyx-breaking-long-formula-lines

I soon realized (when I was making beamer class presentations) that my formula was numbered in the generated PDF. Is there a way to get rid of this numbering without ERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LaTeX preamble, after `\usepackage{breqn}` and the stuff from [the answer I assume you were referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124152/551171) (not the stuff in the comment), add

```
\renewcommand\[{\begin{equation*}}
\renewcommand\]{\end{equation*}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a flexible solution of using `breqn` in LyX at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28964812/4653863

You can use the starred version of the `dmath` environment, i.e., `dmath*` to surround an unnumbered equation which can be created by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> in LyX.